# How to prevent certain items from being added to the cart first in magento1

Tags: cart, magento-1.13

As the title I would like to disable prioritization of certain items from being added to the cart In Magento 1.

For example, I want to treat a product with a price of 0 as not being able to put it in the cart, and put the product with a non-zero price first, followed by the product with a price of 0.

Is there any way?